# Вывод форматированной даты кириллицей из ячейки с типом DATE

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!
В БД дата в ячейке типа DATE устанавливается в виде yyyy-mm-dd. Мне нужно её вывести двумя способами: 1 - в обратном порядке dd-mm-yyyy; 2 - чтобы месяц прописывался кириллицей (5 апреля 2015). Есть какая-то функция, которая может обработать значение массива, в котором содержится дата или какой-нибудь рабочий способ?

Answer (score 1):

Если работаете с кодировкой cp-1251, то можно работать средствами [php](http://www.php.su/setlocale).

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');
```

Если utf-8, например, то можно средствами [mysql](http://dev.ezoterik.info/mysql-i-russkaya-kodirovka/)

P.S. Стоит научится пользоваться поиском по документации [php](https://php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php).

```
date_format(date_create($varible), 'd-m-Y');
```

Comment: это же не вернёт мне отформатированную строку. Кодировка utf-8

Comment: Спасибо! Только в документации вывод месяца, дня недели - на латинице.

Comment: был бы cp1251 можно было бы исправить локалью. А так лепи костыль. `str_replace($month_en, $months_ru, $date);`

Comment: http://gavnokod.com/vyivod-date-php-na-russkom/ - рабочий вариант!